# Looping through Data via LINQ - Performance

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following 2 blocks:

```
var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(t=>whatever == whatever);
foreach (DataRow row in result) //do something
```

and

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    if (row[whatever] == whatever] //do something.
}
```

The first block will ideally have a smaller amount of data to loop through because of the Where clause, and the 2nd block will have to loop through everything.

Is any time saved in block 1 lost because the LINQ query still had to iterate through the entire selection to fulfill the Where?

Comment: Has to iterate though the entire thing to test against the WHERE clause.

Comment: The non-LINQ `foreach` will be faster.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Both examples use `foreach`...

Comment: @JonSkeet doh! hahah.

Comment: @James - Without knowing what optimizations the compiler is going to make, my gut tells me that the second would be faster. In the first you are applying the `Where` in memory on the whole set which is essentially a foreach loop testing for "whatever". The second `foreach` loop in the first snippet will have a smaller resultset to go through, but will be duplicating some of the effort from the `Where`. The second snippet goes through all the rows, but only does it once. The if-block is essentially the same as your equivalency test in the first snippet.

Comment: Additionally to iterating twice (rather than once), the `AsEnumerable()` part in the first version is also wasting a bit of time/resources. On the other hand, LINQ methods are highly optimised and this is a not a too complex query. Best way to know for sure? Actually testing it. If you would have set a (very simplistic) testing framework and check it by your own rather than posting a question here, you would know the answer already.

Comment: Pardon the (incredibly long) delay in replying. After running tests on this against larger and larger datasets the 2nd block (without the `Where`) did ultimately perform better as @Sam had mentioned.